# ListView with nested layout

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

I have a problem for which I've tried many things and this is the solution that may helps finally. I got a listview, that is filled with database data. The user inserts a task and the tasks appear on the screen. The problem is that the user can also inserts subtasks of task and these "new tasks" have to be shown in different rows of the listview under the main task with depth 4. for example:

```
 -Main_Task1
    -SubTask1
       -subtask1
       -subtask2
    -SubTask2
 -Main_Task2
    -SubTask1
       -subtask1
          -subtask1
 -Main_Task3
```

here is the code from the database.

```
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table tasks (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "

    + "title text not null,"
    +"location text not null, " 
    + "body text not null , "
    +" goaldate text not null , "
    +" absolutedate text not null , "
    +" currentdate text not null , "
    +" prio text not null, "
    +" done text not null, "
    +" category text not null, "
    +" timespent text not null, "
    +" pososto text not null, "
    +" father text not null, " 
    +" check1 text not null );";


  // fetch all tasks(tasks and subtasks)
public Cursor fetchTasks() { 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER, KEY_TODAY},null, null, null, null, null);

}

//fetch subtasks of a task, given the father's key
public Cursor fetchSubTasks(String id) { 

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER, KEY_TODAY}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE" + "'"+ id+"'", null, null, null, null);

}


//fetch a subtask
  public Cursor fetchSubTask(String fid,String uid) { // tropopoihsh ths methodou wste   sthn arxiki othoni na fainontai mono oi tasks

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY,KEY_location  , KEY_GOAL_DATE,KEY_ABSOLUTE_DATE, KEY_DATE_CURRENT ,KEY_PRIO,KEY_DONE, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_TIME_SPEND,KEY_POSOSTO, KEY_FATHER, KEY_TODAY}, KEY_FATHER + " LIKE" + " '"+ fid +" '"+ " AND " + KEY_ROWID + " LIKE " + " '"+ uid +"' ", null, null, null, null);

}
```

here is the code from the TasksCursorAdapter class.

```
  LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linear); // fill a textview of   the list with one more textview
          list.removeAllViews();
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

          mCursor = mDbHelper.fetchTasks();//fetching all the tasks
          String id;

          int columnIndex = 0;


          mCursor.moveToFirst();
          while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {

              id = mCursor.getString(0);


              subCursor = mDbHelper.fetchSubTasks(id);// fetching the subtasks with father_id=id


              // Loop through the subCursor
             while(subCursor.moveToNext()) {

                 timeCursor = mDbHelper.fetchSubTask(id, subCursor.getString(columnIndex));// fetching each time the task with the unique id( from the array)
                 //while(timeCursor.moveToNext()){

                  View line = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_row,null);


                  list.addView(line);


              } }

        //  }
```

with this code,i get a listview in which appears a new row in each itemlist, every time that a subtask is added included that the tasks are not fetched properly.any ideas can help.thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add subtasks under each row of the ListView, you should be using [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Comment: the point is that i want to have a depth as I decribed on the schema,so the expandable is not enough.